# Equality of two minimum spanning trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, trees

Given weighted complete undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ vertices and positive weights. Suppose we find minimum spanning tree $MST(G)$ as $T$.Next we want to decrease weight of $n$ edges in $G$  to $-\infty$. So we create new graph $G'=(V,E')$ that contains only edges that have $-\infty$ edge weights. Finally we compute Minimum spanning tree $T'$ from
$T\cup G'$.

My question is, if at the first, decrease spcific edges in $G$ to $-\infty$ and then compute minimum spanning tree $T''$, can we conclude that, edges in $T'$ are the same as $T''$?

Comment: The graph $G'$, contains only edges with $-\infty$ weight, or contains only edges WITHOUT $-\infty$ weight?

Comment: $G'$ contains edges with weight $-\infty$.

Comment: Any tree that has one or more edges with weight $-\infty$ has weight $-\infty$ and is thus a minimal weight tree.

Comment: In the question, you ask whether $T'$ is the same as $T''$, but in the comment you asl whether $T$ is the same as $T''$.

Comment: Excuse me,  i want to know edges set $T'$ is the same edge set. $T''$?